# How do i alert someone using azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Could anyone help out with setting up a logic app that alerts users via another way other than email??
We use function accounts for mail accounts so that alerts can be sent to someone via mail from a logic app but we are looking at whether it can be done via another method other than email.  Thanks in advance. Jay

We tried email accounts linked to a service/function account already

Comment: Have you tried the SMTP or Outlook send mail connector in the logic app? It is very simple.

Comment: Currently the alerts are sent out using email.  The email account is owned by a function/service account but the business would like a different way of doing it because they dont like the issues that come with the management of those kinds of accounts.  Example the owner of the function accounts leaves the company and ownership has to be passed to another employee.  These types of accounts are the only way I know of....hence why Ive asked if theres another way.

Comment: OK, then the answer below should help you to get a push in the right direction. Alerts can be used without a service account, but may lead som some additional costs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-logic-apps?tabs=send-email

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you have other options in create action group for an alert as below:

In alerts section of logic app:

[image]

Then their you can follow like below:

[image]

As you can see we have SMS message, Push and Voice to notify users:

[image]

If you want to use in workflow of logic app thats is also possible as below:

[image]

[image]